# "Anonymous logon" happen once in a while on my machine

Tags: windows-7, security, login, monitoring, session

There is some random "Anonymous logon" session happening once in a while from 3 machines in our company, 3 machines on around 1000.

I have a windows 7 enterprise 64 bits edition. I have all updates installed. I'm a software developer and run as administrator.

Each computer in our company, including mine, have McAfee installed as antivirus.

I wonder what could be the reason for those anonymous logon (virus or anything else) ? If it is a virus, why McAfee does not find it and how can I identify it?

===================================================================

Additional info:

Update: a friend found a useful link but it does not answer the cause : [StackExchange-ServerFault Unexpected anonymous login in Windows security logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/562905/unexpected-anonymous-login-in-windows-security-logs)

- [Logon Types (see type 3)](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/misc_network_security/Logon-Types.html)
- [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/192314/troubling-anonymous-logon-events-in-windows-security-event-log)

I installed NetShareMonitor 1.0 from NagMatrix. This is the session log :

```
***************************************************************
Nov 14 13:23:07 2014 : Session logging started
Nov 14 13:23:39 2014 : Session logging is stopped
***************************************************************
Nov 14 13:23:42 2014 : Session logging started
Nov 14 15:53:05 2014 : Session logging is stopped
***************************************************************
Nov 14 15:54:48 2014 : Session logging started
***************************************************************
Nov 17 09:52:42 2014 : Session logging started
Nov 17 10:03:12 2014 : Session logging is stopped
***************************************************************
Nov 17 10:03:38 2014 : Session logging started
**************************************************************
Nov 17 11:47:10 2014 : Session logging started
***************************************************************
Nov 17 12:08:44 2014 : Session logging started
Nov 17 12:08:47 2014 : Session logging is stopped
***************************************************************
Nov 17 12:56:52 2014 : Session logging started
Nov 17 17:02:08 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PW141850
Nov 17 17:02:32 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PW141850 
Nov 17 17:04:53 2014 : Session logging is stopped
***************************************************************
Nov 17 17:34:11 2014 : Session logging started
Nov 18 09:28:52 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PD140084
Nov 18 09:29:03 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PD140084 
Nov 18 09:29:14 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PD140084
Nov 18 09:29:27 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PD140084 
Nov 18 09:44:35 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PD140084
Nov 18 09:44:51 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PD140084 
Nov 18 09:45:07 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PD140084
Nov 18 09:45:21 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PD140084 
Nov 18 09:58:14 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PD140084
Nov 18 09:58:39 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PD140084 
Nov 18 13:13:57 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PWS00126
Nov 18 13:14:11 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PWS00126 
Nov 18 15:00:14 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PWS00126
Nov 18 15:00:28 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PWS00126 
Nov 19 07:18:20 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PWS00126
Nov 19 07:18:30 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PWS00126 
Nov 19 08:35:29 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is connected from host PWS00126
Nov 19 08:35:42 2014 : User ANONYMOUS LOGON is disconnected from host PWS00126
```

This is a sample from event viewer (each anonymous login look likes the same but the port at the end change from ~50000 - ~65000):

```
+ System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 
   [ Guid]  {54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D} 

   EventID 4624 

   Version 0 

   Level 0 

   Task 12544 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8020000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-11-18T20:00:14.982414900Z 

   EventRecordID 784005 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  760 
   [ ThreadID]  884 

   Channel Security 

   Computer PD130812.ireq.ca 

   Security 


- EventData 

  SubjectUserSid S-1-0-0 
  SubjectUserName - 
  SubjectDomainName - 
  SubjectLogonId 0x0 
  TargetUserSid S-1-5-7 
  TargetUserName ANONYMOUS LOGON 
  TargetDomainName AUTORITE NT 
  TargetLogonId 0x3caeef0 
  LogonType 3 
  LogonProcessName NtLmSsp  
  AuthenticationPackageName NTLM 
  WorkstationName PWS00126 
  LogonGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
  TransmittedServices - 
  LmPackageName NTLM V1 
  KeyLength 128 
  ProcessId 0x0 
  ProcessName - 
  IpAddress **IP of offending machine**
  IpPort 59017
```

Comment: What user accounts exists on this computer.  You have somebody within your network or outside your networking doing a remote connection to this computer.

Comment: Yes that's what is seems to happen. The problem is that it is Anonymous???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the exact cause of the "Anonymous logon" access to my machine. But I saw those random logon from many machines from the same vlan (same sub network). It really sound to be non dangerous and moreover part of the Operating System to discover its neighbors shared resources.

We also can prevent that by turning on some policy or I think by activating the firewall. When I activated the firewall (3 days), I did not received any "Anonymous Logon".

You can see links in question to have a bit more information.

Hope it helps...